# How to find the id which has multiple matchings?

Tags: python, pandas

Given a CSV file(acutally the dataset from Kaggle football data). How to figure out the "player_fifa_api_id” and “player_api_id" that are not one on one matching.

```
player_att.player_fifa_api_id.nunique()
11062

player_att.player_api_id.nunique()
11060
```

The above shows the two are not same.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
player_att = pd.read_csv('Player_Attributes.csv',sep = ',') 
player_att.head()
```

Part of the data show as below:

```
player_fifa_api_id      player_api_id
  218353                       505942
  218353                       505942
  218353                       505942
  218353                       505942
  189615                       155782
  189615                       155782
```

`grouped = player_att.groupby('player_fifa_api_id').count()`

Even I grouped the data, it shows most of the player_fifa_api_id have multiple matichings.

```
player_api_id       player_fifa_api_id  

2625                          14
2752                          17
2768                          17
```

The sample data shows duplicates, however, some `player_api_id` has multiple `player_fifa_api_id`. 
Can anyone tell me how to find this out?

Comment: Not sure what you mean with `How to figure out the "player_fifa_api_id” and “player_api_id" that are not one on one matching?` Do you simply want `player_att[player_att.player_fifa_api_id != player_att.player_api_id]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example if you need just get the player_api_id's that have more than one corresponding player_fifa_api_id you can simply group by player_api_id and then get all the player_api_id that has count() > 1. See the code below:

```
grouped_matches = player_att.groupby('player_api_id').count().reset_index()
non_unique_matches = grouped_matches.loc[grouped_matches['player_fifa_api_id']>1]['player_api_id']
```

The code above will output a list of player_api_id that have multiple player_fifa_api_id. You can do the same for  player_fifa_api_id.